# how to append comment values to respective posts in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Guys im trying to join a comments table to posts table using the following query in a method.

```
public function feedView($session,$friend,$updateid) {
         $sql2=" select  u.update&#95;body,u.author,u.time,u.title,u.account&#95;name,u.update&#95;id,"
            . "c.comment&#95;body, c.os&#95;id,c.author&#95;c,c.time&#95;c,c.comment&#95;id,c.type&#95;c  "
            . "from updates u join comment&#95;update c "
            . "on c.os&#95;id=:statusid WHERE u.account&#95;name = :session or u.account&#95;name=:friend and (u.type = 'a' or 'c') order by u.time asc,c.time&#95;c desc";
    $stmth=  $this->&#95;db->prepare($sql2);
    $stmth->bindValue(":session",$&#95;SESSION['uname']);
    $stmth->bindValue(":friend",$friend);
    $stmth->bindValue(":statusid",$updateid);
    $stmth->execute();
    return $stmth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH&#95;ASSOC);
    }
```

it prints the posts fine but the problem is with comments content where it seems to print the comments in the same posts twice. don't know where the bug is coming from.

here is the DB schema:

here is the how it is displaying feeds:-

[image: comments]

here is the full code for the post and comments logic as asked by partykar:-

```
<?php
include "includes/dbconfig.inc.php";
    $status_replies="";
       $status_list="";
       $statusui_edit="";
       $isowner="";
       $is_friend="";
       $friends = array();
$stmt=  $conn->prepare("select friend_one, friend_two from friends where "
        . "(friend_one=:session OR friend_two=:session) and accepted='1'");
$stmt->bindparam(":session",$_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt->execute();


foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $i=> $r ) {
    $r["friend_one"] == $_SESSION['uname'] ? $friends[]= $r["friend_two"] : $friends[] = $r["friend_one"]; 
$friend=$friends[$i];
//fetch update_id from user table in db and inject it to the feed query.
$status2view=$project->statusView($_SESSION['uname']);
foreach ($status2view as $val) {
   $updateid=$val['update_id'];

//select all relevant posts and comments using the following query and print it.
$feedView=$project->feedView($_SESSION['uname'],$friend,$updateid);

          foreach  ($feedView as $row1) {

                $status_reply_id=$row1['comment_id'];
                $reply_d=htmlentities($row1['comment_body']);
                $reply_data=  stripslashes($reply_d);
                $reply_osid=$row1['os_id'];
                $reply_date=$row1['time_c'];
                $reply_author=$row1['author_c'];
                $updateid=$row1['update_id'];
                $account_name=$row1['account_name'];
                $os_id=$row1['os_id'];
                $author=$row1['author'];
                $post_date=$row1['time'];
                $title= stripslashes($row1['title']);
                $data= stripslashes($row1['update_body']);
                $statusdeletebutton='';     
                $reply_delete_button="";
        if ($reply_author==$_SESSION['uname'] ) {
                   $reply_delete_button="<li><a href='#'type='".$status_reply_id."' class='delete_reply_btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_".$status_reply_id."' title='Delete this comment'> Remove</a></span></li>";
               } 


                         $status_replies="<div  class='replyboxes pull-left reply_".$status_reply_id."'>"
                      . "Reply by:- "
                      . "<a href='home.php?u=".$reply_author."'>".$reply_author."</a>"
                      . "<span class='pull-right'>".$reply_date 
                       . "<b class='dropdown'>
                         <small><span class='btn btn-xs btn-danger dropdown-toggle pull-right' data-toggle='dropdown'  >
                         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></span>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>".$reply_delete_button
                      . "<li><a class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' href='report.php?u=".$reply_author."'> Report</a><li></ul></span>"
                      . "</small></b><br><legend>".  html_entity_decode($reply_data)."</legend><br></div>";




              if ($author==$_SESSION['uname'] || $account_name==$_SESSION['uname']) {
                $statusdeletebutton='<li>'
                           . '<a href="#" type="'.$updateid.'" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_'.$updateid.' glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>';
                $edit_btn='<li>'
                        . '<a href="#" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li>';

                }



                $status_list= $statusui_edit.'<div attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes status_'.$updateid.'  jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left">'
                        . '<div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                         .$edit_btn .' '. $statusdeletebutton .'</ul></div></span><br><hr>'
                        . '<legend><span class=" data_s_2copy" type="'.$updateid.'" >'
                        . html_entity_decode($data).'</span><br><br></legend><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u='.$author.'">'.$author.   '</a>   '.$post_date.'</small></b>'
                        . '<br><p>'.$status_replies.'</p><br>';

                    $status_list.= '<textarea id="reply_textarea_'.$updateid.'"  class="status_reply_'.$updateid.' input-custom2" placeholder="comment\'s"></textarea>'
                            . '<button id="reply_btn_'.$updateid.'" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm reply_btn reply_'.$updateid.'">Reply</button></div>';



               echo "$status_list";




}         }        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling the same method twice?

Comment: the method is in a loop @Andrius

Comment: if you want i can show the code

Comment: Show please @shan2batman

Comment: Just interested: Do you really have all those `&#95;` codes in your source file, or is it a copy/paste oddity?

Comment: sorry about that its a copy/paste act :) @RiggsFolly

Comment: @NanaPartykar did you find anything wrong in the code???

Comment: @shan2batman: I'm trying. Show me `statusView()` function too. Please.

Comment: Problem is in foreach loop. That's why i need statusView() function. And, can you please tell me. Comment and post are in different table ?

Comment: Please give DB Schema of COMMENT and POST table.

Comment: @NanaPartykar is this enough

Comment: One more thing. Is `os_id` in `comment table` is `update_id` in `updates table`.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i will suggest you to check whether the order of your UPDATE and COMMENT coming properly or not.
Don't go for designing. Just check the order. Keep backup of y0ur file. And, Have patience and try this. 
And, check here syntax of this line in both function `$stmth=  $this->$db->prepare($sql2);` of `$db`. (It is correct or not.)

```
<?php
include "includes/dbconfig.inc.php";
$status_replies="";
$status_list="";
$statusui_edit="";
$isowner="";
$is_friend="";
$friends = array();
$stmt=  $conn->prepare("select friend_one, friend_two from friends where (friend_one=:session OR friend_two=:session) and accepted='1'");
$stmt->bindparam(":session",$_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt->execute();

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $i=> $r ) {
    $r["friend_one"] == $_SESSION['uname'] ? $friends[]= $r["friend_two"] : $friends[] = $r["friend_one"]; 
    $friend=$friends[$i];

    //fetch update_id from update table in db and inject it to the feed query.
    $totalUpdates=$project->totalUpdates($_SESSION['uname']);   
    foreach ($totalUpdates as $updates)
    {
        $updateid=$updates['update_id'];
        $updatebody=$updates['update_body'];
        $updatetitle=$updates['title'];
        echo $updatetitle."<br>".$updatebody."<br>";

        // Fetch Comments of update
        $totalComments=$project->totalComments($_SESSION['uname'],$friend,$updateid);   
        foreach($totalComments as $comments)
        {
            echo $comments['comment_body']."<br>";
        }
        echo "<textarea rows='4' placeholder='Comments'></textarea>";
    }

}
```

Create this two functions

```
public function totalComments($session,$friend,$updateid) {
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM comment_update WHERE os_id=:updateid AND (account_name = :session or u.account_name=:friend) AND (type = 'a' or 'c')";
    $stmth=  $this->$db->prepare($sql2); //Check here syntax of $db 
    $stmth->bindValue(":session",$session);
        $stmth->bindValue(":friend",$friend);
        $stmth->bindValue(":updateid",$updateid);
    $stmth->execute();
    return $stmth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
public function totalUpdates($session) {
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM updates WHERE account_name=:session";
    $stmth=  $this->$db->prepare($sql2);//Check here syntax of $db 
    $stmth->bindValue(":session",$session);
    $stmth->execute();
    return $stmth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: it seems to be working let me do some css styling and then get back to you in case of any problems :)

Comment: Hi @shan2batman : I wrote this code for you to bring only the data in a proper way. One more thing, rather than bringing all data in one time, first bring all necessary data. Then, look for css and all validations. I know it will work for you. All the best. Enjoy coding. :) :)

Comment: If it works, then please don't forget to tick it as correct answer. As, it will help other USERS to find answer easily @shan2batman

Answer (score 1):

Your `JOIN` query will duplicate the table records you are joining to, so your news will be printed as many times as the number of comments attached to each post.

I would rather recommend you running different `SELECT` query for comments separately.

Comment: i did exactly as you asked. still, facing the same problem. @NafFIQ